# Div background-color css class fade effect?

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to add a fade effect to a div on mouse over. The fade effect is to transition between colors for `background-color`. While I can change the css class instantaneously, using `fadeIn()` or `animate()` have not been useful at creating the fade animation. How can I go about creating this animation?

jQuery:

```
$('div.my-bkgr').mouseover(function() {
  $('div.my-bkgr').attr("class", "my-bkgr-mouseover");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $('div.my-bkgr').attr("class", "my-bkgr");
});
```

CSS:

```
.my-bkgr {
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
}

.my-bkgr-mouseover {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just using the [`transition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) property and specifying a `transition-duration` to your needs? e.g

```
.my-bkgr  {
background-color: #ECF0F1;
transition: all 3s ease-out; /* Include vendor prefixes before this */
}

.my-bkgr:hover {
background-color: #E74C3C;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Humility/wNQDX/)

Comment: Thanks! I was so stuck on using jQuery I forgot about this CSS property.

Comment: Transitioning on 'all' is discouraged, it's better to specify exactly what you want the transition to apply to (see other answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this with plain css:

```
.my-bkgr {
  background: #ECF0F1;
  /* A transition of 0.3 seconds */
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
 }
.my-bkgr:hover {
  background: #E74C3C;
}
```

Or use jQuery UI if you want IE support: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS transitions.

```
.my-bkgr{
    -webkit-transition: color 2s ease;
       -moz-transition: color 2s ease;
        -ms-transition: color 2s ease;
         -o-transition: color 2s ease;
            transition: color 2s ease;
}
```

---

**Source(s)**

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/

http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score -1):

jQuery docs have an example here of how to do what you want: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Simply replace click with the required event you want. So maybe try this (off the top of my head)

```
$('div.my-bkgr').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).effect("highlight", {
      colour: #E74C3C
    }, 3000);
});
```